# How to copy specific tags and its content in a file?

Tags: python, regex, copy, paste

I have a txt file, that contains many strings like this:

```
<tag1><style="1">"Lorem ipsum dolor...</style>"Lorem Ipsum dolor"</tag1><tag1>"Other Lorem ipsum Dolor"</tag1><tag1>"Lorem ipsum DOLOR"</tag1>
```

What I want to do is to copy each found by regex pattern string and paste its copy underneath of each of the single matches, then change the specific  name in the copied string to "tagen1, so the result would look like this:

```
<tag1><style="1">"Lorem ipsum dolor...</style>"Lorem Ipsum dolor"</tag1><tagen1><style="1">"Lorem ipsum dolor...</style>"Lorem Ipsum dolor"</tagen1>
<tag1>"Other Lorem ipsum Dolor"</tag1><tagen1>"Other Lorem ipsum Dolor"</tagen1><tag1>"Lorem ipsum DOLOR"</tag1><tagen1>"Lorem ipsum DOLOR"</tag1>
```

etc.

I am not really sure how to proceed from there:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'<tag1>(.+?)<\/tag1>')

with open(f1) as f: 
    f1 = pattern.findall(f.read())

copy = list(zip(f1))

#here I'd like to perform copying from "copy" list to the file.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, it's also not clear you've tried an actual solution to your problem - can I suggest you change the example to be less messy and instead of mashing the keyboard, put some straight-forward example input in there that makes it clearer what you intend to happen?

Comment: Hi Grismar, thanks for looking into it. I have edited the example, I hope it's more clear now. I am looking for a solution for copying some regex found tags in a document, then pasting each match underneath each match with changed tag name, then save the document.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best idea to do this task with regular expressions, yet if we have to do so in part, we would start with a general expression to just capture the tags, then we would script the rest of our problem, if we wish.

There should likely be some sort of library/package that'd help us for this.

To capture tags,

```
(<([\w\s=\"]+?)>)|(<\/([\w]+?)>)|(.+?)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBHjWh/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<([\w\s=\"]+?)>)|(<\/([\w]+?)>)|(.+?)"

test_str = "<tag1><blah =\"1\">\"sdfhds^\"</blah>\"*@$%\"</tag1><some_different_tag>\"aihdihihaif\"</some_different_tag><tag1>\"92763972649@^&^(@$<>ihagHGWi!_*#&)!#&@#$!^#\"</tag1><tag1>\"sdwuqioyewoqiuy&%*(&!*#%(*!#$!$ 4545___)0rrf\"</tag1>"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yBHjWh/1/).